# How to setup HTTPS express server on AKS with ingress controller

Tags: express, https, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I've deployed my express server on AKS in `HTTP` Mode as a `ClusterIP`. Then I'm using nginx ingress controller to host my setup over HTTPS. I've followed these steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls to setup automatic TLS for the ingress.

I'm able to access my express server over HTTPS properly. But Making API calls to my express server using my frontend, is using `HTTP` protocol instead of `HTTPS`. Due to which cookies are not being sent.

Is there any way to power the express server using the same certificates that are being used by ingress? How can I even run my express server in HTTPS mode behind an Ingress?